# Ruby regex to remove newlines from specifc HTML tag?

Tags: html, ruby, regex

Sorry I'm really bad at regexes, I finally hacked osmething to work in ruby.  I'd appreciate if someone can instruct the proper way of how to do this:

I basically wanted to remove all \n when it appears within ul tags.

```
while body =~ /<ul>.*(\n+).*<\/ul>/m
  body =~ /<ul>(.+)<\/ul>/m
  body.gsub!(
    /<ul>(.+)<\/ul>/m,
    "<ul>#{$1.gsub("\n","")}</ul>" )
end
```

The 2nd line took me forever to figure out, since the $1 was from the while loop, not actually from the gsub statement.

Thanks!

Comment: But, why does this matter? Unless you have a <pre> or something inside your list (or unless you have some postprocessing code that subsequently converts all newlines to <br> tags), the document won't be any different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regexp's TIMTOWTDI but here's one shorter attempt:

```
body.gsub!(/<ul>.*?<\/ul>/m) {|m| m.tr("\n",'') }
```

Basically find (non-greedily) all ul-tags and replace them with all linefeeds removed (check RDoc for [String.gsub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000839) and [String.tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000845))